# Scroll to a hidden section after data load in Angular

Tags: angular, scroll

I'm doing my first app in Angular. I choosed basic weather app and I have a problem. I want to scroll to the section after data load from API. This section is hidden until a data load. I didn't have problem how to do in in Vanilla JS but in Angular I have some problems.

```
startApp = (event: Event): void => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  this.showCurrentWeather(); //load data
  this.sectionWithDataClass = 'section section--weather'; //show hidden section
  this.scroll.scrollToAnchor('currentWeatherSection') 
}
```

My main problem is that the scroll to the section works after the second click on the button. First click just load the data and change class of the hidden section.

Comment: Is this startApp the click event on your button?   This seems like you need to separate the data fetch from the button click.  Can you show more of the component code that this is in?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your `this.showCurrentWeather()` method is asynchronous inside. At the beginning, there is no current weather section in the DOM, so you have to wait for it somehow.

You can make your method return Promise and use like this:

```
  event.stopPropagation();
  this.showCurrentWeather().then(() => {
    this.sectionWithDataClass = 'section section--weather'; //show hidden section
    this.scroll.scrollToAnchor('currentWeatherSection') 
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not working. Still I need to click 2-times the button to scroll to the section. Maybe it's because of a change detection in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

I added changedetectionstrategy.onpush and called the change detection after fetching data from API and that's work really fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).